# Hexa decimal string format

Tags: c

Is it possible to directly convert integer to hexadecimal in the following way?

```
Integer Value = 145635

hexa decimal value (4 bytes) = 0x000238E3

<0x00><0x02><0x38><0xE3>
```

I have tried with %x. But that doesn't work for me. 
Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), expected and real outputs, which demonstrate your problem. Also, what exactly do you mean by "convert to hexadecimal"? Do you want to convert `int` to some string which holds the integer in hexadecimal?

Comment: "*But that does not help me.*" Why?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the output with the `<..>` surrounding each byte at least with one `printf`-statement as follows. Note that data type is unsigned, which is better in conjunction with hex and with bit shift operators:

```
unsigned int val = 145635; 
// "ordinary" printf  
printf("%08X\n", val);       

// printf per byte:
printf("<%02X><%02X><%02X><%02X>\n",
       val >> 24,
       (val&0x00ff0000) >> 16,
       (val&0x0000ff00) >> 8,
       val&0x000000ff);
```

Comment: `%02x` ----> `%02X`  to achieve the desired output

Comment: Plus one, but not sure if this is what the OP actually wants.